# Turns multiline cells into separate lines

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet like this:

Reference Sheet:

| Text | Main Category | Category | Subcategory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples Oranges Bananas | Shopping | Goods | Fruits |
| One of a Kind | One of a Kind | One of a Kind | One of a Kind |
| Non Cat Item | No Category |  |  |
| Bread Pasta | Shopping | Goods | Groceries |

Apples, Oranges, and Bananas are in the same cell, separated by linebreaks.

I need a formula that can automatically update another sheet based on the first one to this structure:

Transformed sheet

| Text | Main Category | Category | Subcategory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | Shopping | Goods | Fruits |
| Oranges | Shopping | Goods | Fruits |
| Bananas | Shopping | Goods | Fruits |
| One of a Kind | One of a Kind | One of a Kind | One of a Kind |
| Non Cat Item | No Category |  |  |
| Bread | Shopping | Goods | Groceries |
| Pasta | Shopping | Goods | Groceries |

I've tried in :

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(CHAR(10), Reference!A:A), CHAR(10)))
```

But it doesn't work with the empty cells. How do I transform the Reference sheet into the format shown in the Transformed sheet?

Comment: What does not work, when you say: "But it doesn't work with the empty cells"?  You do know the function `ISBLANK()` ? This checks for empty cells...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,index(match(,0/(A2:A<>""))),
     reduce(A1:D1,sequence(Σ),lambda(a,c,iferror(vstack(a,let(Λ,tocol(iferror(split(index(A2:A,c),char(10)))),hstack(Λ,chooserows(index(B2:D,c),sequence(counta(Λ),1,1,0)))))))))
```

[image]